# Meteor - Return .find doesn't return the correct data

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to return only the data for a specific user. However my return classes.find doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
Template.classes.helpers({
    studentProfileId: () => {
        return FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    }
    classes: ()=> {
        return Classes.find({id: studentProfileId});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a variable and use FlowRouter.getParam to access the user id.

```
Template.classes.helpers({
    studentProfileId: () => {
        return FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    }
    classes: () => {
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        return Classes.find({studentProfileId: id});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the data available to the client:

```
Template.classes.onCreated(function() {
   this.subscribe('Classes', FlowRouter.getParam('id'));
});
```

and to use a variable in the helpers as well..

```
Template.classes.helpers({
    classes: function() {
        return Classes.find({studentProfileId: FlowRouter.getParam('id')});
    }
});
```